# TTS play silence in a for-loop doesn`t work

Tags: android, while-loop, text-to-speech

I want to add a pause button to my TTS-app. I am trying to do this with a while-loop, which should playSIlence. It isn't working, but I can't find my mistake.

my boolean:

```
    boolean pausegedrückt;
```

for-loop:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < anzahl+1; i++) {
         while (pausegedrückt==true) {
            tts.playSilence(1000, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        }

            String str = String.valueOf(i);
            tts.speak(str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            tts.playSilence(3000, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null); 

        }
```

my onCheckedChanged

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        l.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        pausegedrückt=false;
    } else {
        l.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        pausegedrückt=true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding an [OnUtteranceCompletedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html) or an [UtteranceProgressListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html) as utterances can fail on some devices without it.

Also, you are adding 1 second of silence to the queue for each loop. If it loops 10,000 times, you're going to end up with a lot of silence..... You need the loop inside the utterance listener (or at least another boolean parameter), so it will only add a further 1 second of silence once the previous silence finishes.

That said, I don't think this is the right approach to pausing the speech.