# Text to Speech android not working

Tags: android, text-to-speech

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    init();
}

public void init() {
    tts = new TextToSpeech(Game.this, new OnInitListener() {
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                 tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                 speakout("Hello Gies");
            }
        }
    });
}

public void speakout(String text) {
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    tv2.setText("" + text);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

The code runs fine. I am trying to covert the text to speech but the I am unable to find the desired output. Please help me out with a fix.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'find the desired output' ? You also should add an  utterance listener - See the links in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22642640/1256219

Answer (score 2):

You should not use tts reference before onInit is called with success, and from your code its clear you are calling speakout just after creating TextToSpeech class. Move `speakout("Hello Gies");` to inside your `onInit`. Also if you shutdown your tts in onPause then you better recreate it in onResume - this means you can actually move your `init();` to `onResume`.

Comment: i have tried your suggestion but the code doesnt works i have edited my code again. Can you help me with a working code?

Comment: look into logcat, it often gives hints on whats wrong - otherwise I dont see why it does not work.

Comment: it says initTts() failed to bind the service

Comment: I am not sure whats wrong, I think you should start with ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA, after its return you will know if all the resources are installed.